# Botones con ventanas modales de una tabla me muestran la misma información

Tags: java, html, css

Tengo una tabla con varias columnas, ciertos *datos son muy largos*, por esta razón y para ahorrar espacio, decidí usar **botones** los cuales me muestren **una ventana modal** con los *datos largos* de esa columna.

La primera fila con los botones funciona como debe ser, mostrando los datos en **la ventana modal** y en la tabla se ve **el boton que abre la modal** como se ve a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Inesperadamente, al empezar la segunda Fila, me siguen cargando los datos de la primera y asi suvesivamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero lograr es que se muestre la información debida para cada boton, **he intentado buscar respuestas y las he encontrado** pero desafortunadamente **no la entiendo** o usan alguna **solucion de PHP** que no estoy usando/no funciona o de por si usan otro tipo de modal.

El problema no es el BackEnd, he hecho pruebas y como el titulo dice *"Botones con ventanas modales de una tabla me muestran la misma información."* ya que en una de las pruebas descubrí que **el boton es el problematico** ya que cuando quito el boton y quito el div que oculta la modal, se ve lo que se debe ver:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puede ser que la solución pueda ser tonta o no la veo a simple vista, pero ya no pude lograrlo y pues acudo aqui, a continuación mostraré el codigo:

**css:**

```
 <style>
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;

}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
</style>
```

**HTML (Solamente el Tbody & Tabla):**
La zona a la que me refiero es la que está comentada con las partes del modal.

```
<tbody>
        <c:forEach var="test" items="${test}">
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">${test.getIdvcp()}</th>
            <td>${test.getRequser()}</td>
            <td>${test.getEstado()}</td>
            <td>
            <!---MODAL-->
                <!--Boton-->    
                <a type="button" href="#openModal1"  class="btn btn-outline-light"><i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i></a>
                <!-- Abrir modal -->    
                <div id="openModal1" class="modalDialog"> 
                    <!--Cuerpo del modal -->
                    <div class="card" id="openModal1" style="margin-left: 420px;width: 25rem;">
                         <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Pre-Requisitos</h5>
                            <p id="info1" class="card-text">${test.getPrereq()}</p>
                            <a href="#close" value="salir" type="button" style="float: right"class="btn btn-outline-danger">Cerrar ventana</a>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!---MODAL-->
            </td>
            <td>${test.getPasos()}
            <td>${test.getEsperado()}</td>
            <td>${test.getObtenido()}</td>
            <td>${test.getObserv()}</td>
            <td>${test.getEjecutor()}</td>
            <td>${test.getResponsable()}</td>
            <td>${test.getIdproyvcp()}</td>
            <td>${test.getIduservcp()}</td>
            <td>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-warning" href="Controlador?menu=tester&accion=cargar&id=${test.getIdvcp()}"><i class="fa-solid fa-hand-pointer"></i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" style="margin-top:5px" href="Controlador?menu=tester&accion=eliminar&id=${test.getIdvcp()}"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></a> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
```

Si se requiere mas codigo, puedo mostrarlo, pero realmente pienso que esto es suficiente ya que buscando parece ser problemas de las id, pero muevo que muevo y nada.

**Algo a aclarar es que esta no es la primera modal de esta parte del proyecto, la primera es una en la que me abre un formulario, la cual, pues no veo problema de mover.**

Para traer los datos uso una lista, a parte de que uso el lenguaje java
Tambien **no** uso nada de javascript para las modales, simplemente es css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diria que estás abriendo todo el rato el mismo modal, el primero que encuentra con ese **id**, con esto:

```
<a type="button" href="#openModal1"
```

pues el modal lo identificas así:

```
<div id="openModal1" class="modalDialog">
```

y duplicar ids en HTML **nunca** es una buena idea, deben ser únicos.

Podrias mirar de conseguirlo usando alguna de las variables que tienes, para modificarlo por ejemplo así:

```
<a type="button" href="#openModal1_${test.getIdvcp()}"
```

y hacer lo mismo con su **div**:

```
<div id="openModal1_${test.getIdvcp()}" class="modalDialog">
```

así lo llamarias de forma única a cada uno de ellos.